# Persisting data to Rails API from ObjectController via input checkbox helper

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ember.js, ember-cli, rails-api

Currently running on Ember-CLI 0.1.2 and Rails-API.

Following the official TodoMVC tutorial on the EmberJS website here: http://emberjs.com/guides/getting-started/marking-a-model-as-complete-incomplete/ and implementing with a rails backend for data persistence with the tutorial here: http://blaketv.com/2014/06/17/ember-cli-todomvc-tutorial/#marking-a-model-as-complete-or-incomplete

The data is being served by my rails API:

```
ember server --proxy http://localhost:3000

# ember/app/adapters/application.js
import DS from 'ember-data';

export default DS.ActiveModelAdapter.extend({
  namespace: 'api/v1'
});

# ember/app/routes/todos/index.js
import Ember from 'ember';

export default Ember.Route.extend({
  model: function() {
    return this.store.find('todo');
  }
});

# rails/app/controllers/api/v1/todos_controller.rb
class Api::V1::TodosController < ApplicationController
  def index
    render json: Todo.all
  end

  def show
    render json: Todo.find(params[:id])
  end

  def create
    @todo = Todo.new(todo_params)

    if @todo.valid? && @todo.save
      render json: @todo, status: 201
    end
  end

  def update
    @todo = Todo.find(params[:id])

    if @todo.update_attributes(todo_params)
      render json: @todo, status: 200
    end
  end

  private

  def todo_params
    params.require(:todo).permit(:title, :is_completed)
  end
end
```

I have an input helper:

```
# ember/app/templates/todos/index.hbs
{{#each}}
  <li {{bind-attr class="isCompleted:completed"}}>
    {{input type="checkbox" checked=isCompleted class="toggle"}}
    <label>{{title}}</label>
    <button class="destroy"></button>
  </li>
{{/each}}
```

I can see the list of my todos served by rails on the index template without a problem. My issue is that when I click on one of the checkboxes, it should call the `isCompleted` function in the TodoController, and persist the changed data via rails but that doesn't happen:

```
# ember/app/controllers/todo.js
import Ember from 'ember';

export default Ember.ObjectController.extend({
  isCompleted: function(key, value) {
    var model = this.get('model');

    if (value === undefined) {
      // property being used a getter
      return model.get('isCompleted');
    } else {
      // property being used a setter
      model.set('isCompleted', value);
      model.save();
      return value;
    }
  }.property('model.isCompleted')
});
```

The function is run, the `isCompleted` property of the model gets changed and the `li` tag gets the `completed` class, but the data is not persisted and saved in my database. I can't seem to find out why. I have tried reading the ember documentation and have tried different things like putting the `isCompleted` function inside an actions property and using the `DS.Store.update` method. I don't see any errors in my browser's ember inspector or ember server logs.

I have an ArrayController that has a createTodo action and it works, it interacts with my rails API endpoint and persists the todo in my database just fine.

```
# ember/app/controllers/todos/index.js
import Ember from 'ember';

export default Ember.ArrayController.extend({
  actions: {
    createTodo: function() {
      // Get the todo title set by the "New Todo" text field
      var title = this.get('newTitle');
      if (!title.trim()) { return; }

      // Create the new Todo Model
      var todo = this.store.createRecord('todo', {
        title: title,
        isCompleted: false
      });

      // Clear the "New Todo" text field
      this.set('newTitle', '');

      // Save the new model
      todo.save();
    }
  }
});
```

Any help in better understanding how to do this would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Turns out that I had to pass an `itemController` property in my each helper:

from:

```
{{#each}}
  <li {{bind-attr class="isCompleted:completed"}}>
    {{input type="checkbox" checked=isCompleted class="toggle"}}
    <label>{{title}}</label>
    <button class="destroy"></button>
  </li>
{{/each}}
```

to:

```
{{#each itemController="todo"}}
  <li {{bind-attr class="isCompleted:completed"}}>
    {{input type="checkbox" checked=isCompleted class="toggle"}}
    <label>{{title}}</label>
    <button class="destroy"></button>
  </li>
{{/each}}
```

After this change, the `isCompleted` function in my Todo ObjectController works and persists data through rails.